# Linux from Binaries

Tags: linux, binary, lfs

I thought Linux from Scratch was a pretty cool tutorial, but I felt having to wait for everything to compile was a bit nerve-wreaking.

Is there a tutorial similar to LFS except pre-compiled binaries are used whenever possible? I would imagine that if you were running a specific liveCD (e.g. Ubuntu) you could just copy over a lot of the pieces of the liveCD for the system you're  building (e.g. kernel, libraries, executables, etc.).

Comment: Isn't “Linux from binaries” the same as “a typical Linux distribution”?

Comment: @Gilles I suppose so, but that isn't quite what I meant. In theory, if the Ubuntu installer downloaded all the sources, and compiled all sources during installation, you could call that "Linux from Scratch" too right? The title "LFB" was meant to be a reference to "LFS" -- more of a tutorial than an actual distribution that teaches you how to build a "Linux" from source/scratch/binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A less time consuming option is [Gentoo Linux](http://www.gentoo.org/).  The install process starts further along than the Linux From Scratch book and there are options to install some of the bigger packages from binary to avoid compiling your Desktop Environment from scratch for example.

As a side note the only reason to install Linux from Scratch is as a educational experience.